# Creating string index with Code first

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance, entity-framework, indexing

I'm using Entity Framework 6.1 code-first and my domain model is below.

```
class Item
{
    [Index]
    public string CreatedBy { set; get; }
}
```

When I use update-database for migration, I get the following error. However as far as I researched `[Index]` should work as annotation to `string`.

> Column 'CreatedBy' in table 'dbo.Items' is of a type that is invalid for use as a key column in an index.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Usually you get this error when you use a VARCHAR(Max) try using:

```
[Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR")]
[StringLength(n)]
[Index]
public string CreatedBy { set; get; }
```

where n is between 1 and 450.

Comment: As [Talal Yousif](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4023562/talal-yousif) said, you get this error when you use a VARCHAR(Max), but you can fix this by adding StringLength attribut only. [StringLength(n)] [Index] public string CreatedBy { set; get; }

Comment: Why the `[Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR")]` attribute?

Comment: @Zero3 nvarchar is unicode (2bytes/char), and varchar is not (1byte/char). So in case your field does not require different languages (codepages) you can have twice the space.

Comment: @TalalYousif if you defined `VARCHAR` you can select `1 < n < 900`.

Comment: @TomerW So in other words, the `Column` attribute is irrelevant to the answer?

Comment: @Zero3 not directly, the short answer is that Keys are allowed up to 900byte length...

Comment: @TomerW Ahh, that is a significant piece of information missing from the answer. Thanks!

Comment: You should probably be using `NVARCHAR` instead of `VARCHAR` -- you're using .net strings, and who knows what type of data users will enter into your fields... (email addresses for example can contain unicode characters, so can pretty much everything else).

Answer (score 5):

If you use EntityTypeConfiguration aka mappings  :

```
public class MyPocoEntitiyTypeConfig<T> : EntityTypeConfiguration<T> where T:class
{

}

public class MyPocoEnt
{
    public virtual string MyProp { get; set; }
}

public class MyPocoEntMapping : MyPocoEntitiyTypeConfig<MyPocoEnt>
{
    public MyPocoEntMapping()
    {
            Property(x => x.MyProp).HasMaxLength(300);
            Property(x => x.MyProp).HasColumnAnnotation("Index", new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("MyProp") { IsUnique = true }));
        }
    }
}
```