# EntityFramework one Entity used by two Entities

Tags: model, frameworks, entity, relationship, code-first

I am using CodeFirst. I have one entity with addresses, that's used by customers and prospectives.

They both can have multiple addresses. So I have a one-many relationship between customers and addresses, and a one-many relationship between prospectives and addresses.

What is the best way to build my model?

Answer (score 0):

First ask yourself if there is any difference, even subtle, between the customer address and prospective address? Does the address of the customer has some additional properties then the prospective address? Can they both have billing/shipping address or just the customer? If there are differences you can split the single address into two because you will easily evolve them when they are separate.

There is no problem to model it with the Visual Studio model builder or with Mappings, aka implementations of EntityTypeConfiguration like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27687982/1042934) and the docs and emaples for the code first mappings [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx). I do not see any problem to get foreign key to both Customer and Prospect from Address table.