ef core unique constraint for 2 different entities
Lets say I have 2 entities, there is no relationship between them
I wanted to make sure in db I have unique addresses so I tried the following
public class SaleAddress : SaveConfig
        {
            [Key]
            [Required]
            public Guid SaleAddressId { get; set; }
            public Guid SignatureId { get; set; }
            public string Address { get; set; }
        }
    
        public class DepositAddress : SaveConfig
        {
    
            [Key]
            [Required]
            public Guid DepositAddressId { get; set; }
            public int? Index { get; set; }  
            public bool Active { get; set; }
            public Guid SignatureId { get; set; }
            public string Address { get; set; }
        }

I created constraint for unique address
modelBuilder.Entity<SaleAddress>()
             .HasIndex(e => e.Address)
             .IsUnique();

         // Ensure Address is unique no duplicated address
         modelBuilder.Entity<DepositAddress>()
             .HasIndex(e => e.Address)
             .IsUnique();

is it possible to also prevent to have same (saleaddress) Address in depositaddress table and vice versa or do I have to manually check before insert
Example. Lets say I want to insert new deposit addresses
var depositAddress = new DepositAddress
        {
            Address = "Foo"
        };
 await _repository.DepositAddressesRepository.Add(depositAddress);


var depositAddress = new DepositAddress
        {
            Address = "Foo1"
        };
 await _repository.DepositAddressesRepository.Add(depositAddress);
     await _repository.SaveAsync();   

//above will go through "Foo" and "Foo1" are unique
//the following should throw exception because there is already "Foo1" in deposit address
var saleAddress = new SaleAddress
        {
            Address = "Foo1"
        };
 await _repository.SaleAddressesRepository.Add(saleAddress);
     await _repository.SaveAsync();

is this possible to somehow configure this in efcore or do i have to manually check before insert

A few things are going on here.
Firstly I think that because your Sales Address object is using GUIDS for uniqueness, there is no constraint to say that the names aka. Address of type string has to be unique.
Maybe you could decorate the Address with something like this:
[Index(IsUnique = true)]
Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52222577/entity-framework-unique-constraint-on-a-string-column

It can be done using triggers.

Why not store them in one table? SaleAddress can easily be always Active and have Index = null. Just add a type field, but it's not even necessary to use TPH inheritance, although you could. Then you can simply make the Address field unique by an index.

@GertArnold I am sorry most properties in the object I omitted, need to keep them separate due to other relationships,(other tables)

@AlexanderPetrov could you pls give me the idea how?

Still, I think you have to create one table that contains the part that should be unique. It looks like you need one of the inheritance patterns EF supports.

Search for "sql triggers on two tables". To give a more specific solution, we need to know which DBMS you are using. But in any case, the solution based on triggers is quite bad, because it is cumbersome and will be inefficient in performance. If I were you, I would listen to Gert Arnold's advice.

Child types in a TPH can have navigations to other tables. EF Core will generate sql joins with the discriminator filter. The foreign key columns will be nullable. Sql Server Unique indexes can also have filters.

I don't think SQL databases allows that kind of coupling, but even if it's somehow accomplished, the tables insertion now will fail because another table has it already, therefore you still need to check if the data already exists before you insert.
Two ideas I can suggest:
1. Check before insertion

Your problem is more about business logic rather than data logic, and writing business logic in your program is perfectly fine.
2. Combine the tables

If they are both addresses, and you don't actually have need to separate them, simply make an address table and have a field to indicate the type of the address. You can then apply unique index on that table, making things easier.

the address table is probably the best solution and easiest solution for me ATM, simple and effective
